# How to create a dialog with Open AI GPT using CoreML?

Tags: swift, nlp, coreml

[image]

With the introduction of CoreML 3 in the slides they show **Open AI GPT**. So my assumptions is they integrated GPT into CoreML. Would that make it possible to have a conversation with a bot?

The problem is I have spent hours on the internet trying to find how to implement this and was not able to find the answer. I did find:

```
"NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.lemma])" for Lemmatization.
"NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.nameType])" for identifying names.
"NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.sentimentScore])" for sentiment.
"NLLanguageRecognizer" to determine dominant language.
"UITextChecker" for spell checking and correction.
```

This is all used for analyzing text. But from my understanding GPT can be used for dialog and text generation as well.

https://github.com/huggingface/swift-coreml-transformers

Came close with GPT-2 text generation. However if I download it won't compile because of model issues. Is there anyone that knows how this can be accomplished? Preferabele using CoreML?

Comment: I don't think the slide means that Apple integrated `GPT` into `CoreML`. I think it means that theoretically possible to convert a `GPT` model into a `CoreML` model using `coremltools`.

Comment: Yep, my hunch was correct. If they had made GPT available, it would be here: https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/models/#text